# MVVMCross: Use LegacyBar with MvxDialogActivity issue

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I use LegacyBar https://github.com/Cheesebaron/LegacyBar with MvxDialogActivity in [MVVMCross](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross)

I have a LegacyBar sample as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/TestAndroid"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

  <legacybar.library.bar.LegacyBar
     android:id="@+id/actionbar"
     style="@style/actionbar"
        />

  <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code:

```
[Activity(Label = "TestAndroid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var legacyBar = FindViewById<LegacyBar.Library.Bar.LegacyBar>(Resource.Id.actionbar);
            legacyBar.SetDropDown(this, new string[] { "My First Account", "My Second Account", "My Third Account" }, DropDownSelected);
        }

        private void DropDownSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs args)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this, "You selected account: " + args.Position, ToastLength.Short).Show());
        }
    }
```

I run OK, then I add reference to MvvmCross, and I create another view

```
public class TestDialogView : MvxDialogActivity
    {
    }
```

I Press F5 to run the application, and the following error`enter code here`:

Unhandled Exception:
07-31 01:30:53.752 E/mono    ( 1526): System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Drawable ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
07-31 01:30:53.752 E/mono    ( 1526):   at Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.m_*D1 (System.Reflection.Assembly ass) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bigsplash/0e0e51f9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/ResourceIdManager.cs:21 
07-31 01:30:53.752 E/mono    ( 1526):   at Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues () [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bigsplash/0e0e51f9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/ResourceIdManager.cs:22 
07-31 01:30:53.752 E/mono    ( 1526):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Droid.Resource+Drawable..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
07-31 01:30:53.752 E/mono    ( 1526):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
07-31 01:30:53.752 E/mono    ( 1526):   at [ProjectName].Resource.UpdateIdValues () [0x00001] in c:\DATA\Working\Rabiti[ProjectName]-MonoDroid[ProjectName]\Resources\Res
07-31 01:30:53.762 I/mono    ( 1526): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Drawable ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
07-31 01:30:53.762 I/mono    ( 1526):   at Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.m*_D1 (System.Reflection.Assembly ass) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bigsplash/0e0e51f9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/ResourceIdManager.cs:21 
07-31 01:30:53.762 I/mono    ( 1526):   at Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues () [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bigsplash/0e0e51f9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/ResourceIdManager.cs:22 
07-31 01:30:53.762 I/mono    ( 1526):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Droid.Resource+Drawable..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
07-31 01:30:53.762 I/mono    ( 1526):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
07-31 01:30:53.762 I/mono    ( 1526):   at [ProjectName].Resource.UpdateIdValues () [0x00001] in c:\DATA\Working\Rabiti[ProjectName]-MonoDroid[ProjectName]\

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: In LegacyBar sample project, I add nuget reference to MvvmCross.HotTuna.Droid.Dialog, the same error occurs.

Comment: Can you show some code. I don't really understand how you are using it. The stack trace indicates something is Null somewhere.

Comment: Could you check sample code at [http://sdrv.ms/19CjLV5](http://sdrv.ms/19CjLV5)

Comment: Sorry I am not going to download a random zip file from an untrusted source. You have the possibility to explain what you are doing here on Stack Overflow, you can post code snippets etc. This will also preserve the QA form Stack Overflow uses and persist code in the question for others to see in the future.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the question. Thank you!

Comment: I'd guess this is a monodroid issue with importing multiple resource projects - maybe try xamarin for help. If xam can't import multiple projects then you might be able to add the resources directly to your UI project